# What's the relation between henselianization and completion?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

It's a short question, namely

> When can one think about the henselianization $A^h$ of a local ring $A$ as the "algebraic part" of its completion $\hat{A}$?

It seems to be true for $k[\vec{x}]$, where $\vec{x}$ is a bunch of indeterminants.

And clearly there is a morphism from $A^h$ to $\hat{A}$.

Are there more general situation where $A^h$ embeds into $\hat{A}$ as the algebraic part?

(In case this is not a good question, let me ask a different one: what's a good way to think about $A^h$?)

Comment: Ray's reference here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/88072/how-to-compute-the-henselization-of-some-simple-rings/88241#88241 might be useful.